# After I put a redirect code, the login form isn't working

Tags: php

I've set a redirect from my index.php to form.php which there's a login form inside. But the login form isn't working, after I logged in it stayed at form.php

I put this code for the redirect in index.php :

```
<?php
    header('Location: form.php');
    exit();
?>
```

I expect the login form to be working after I put the redirect code in index.php

Comment: once you logged in you definitely maintained the session? Am I right?  On the index page check, the session has those values, if yes then stay on the page otherwise redirect to the login page.

Comment: Too minimal. All this shows is a redirect, which would redirect the use to `form.php`  everytime this is executed.

Comment: We don't know what's in "form.php" or what "isn't working" really means in reality. "After I logged in it stayed at form.php"...ok so what code did you put in "form.php" to make the user do anything after they logged in? At a guess, do you really mean "stayed at form.php" or, is the reality actually "user gets redirected from form.php to index.php, and is then immediately redirected back to form.php" (due to the code shown in your question)? Check your browser's network tool while testing to see what actually happens.

Comment: If you want to redirect someone from your protected pages back to your login form, you must first check that they don't have a valid login session, otherwise they'll always be redirected no matter what. So it's expected you set a Session value when they successfully log in, and you then check for the existence of that session value on every other page which requires the user to be logged in in order to access it. P.S. There are so many PHP tutorials about authentication and login online which show what to do...there's really no reason to be stuck on this part as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like once the login is made, you are getting redirected back to the login page, try this.

```php
//index.php
// Change user_id to whatever session you are setting
if ( !isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
  exit(header('Location: form.php'));
}
```

If you want to block access to the login page once logged in, do the same but check if the session is set.

```php
//form.php
if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
  exit(header('Location: index.php'));
} else {
  // login code
}
```